# Getting Data From Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller and service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.service("BrandService", ['$http', function($http){
this.reloadlist = function(){
    var list;
     $http.get('/admin.brands/getJSONDataOfSearch').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          list = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
     return list;
};
```

}]);

```
app.controller('BrandsCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$controller','BrandService', function($scope, $http, $controller, BrandService) {
    $scope.brands = BrandService.reloadlist();
    angular.extend(this, $controller("BrandCtrl", {$scope: $scope}));
}]);
```

I searched for this issue and tried answers of questions but I couldn't get solution. I am new at angular so can you explain with details; why I couldn't get the data from service to controller this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return used for data is for the callback of your function.
You must use the promise returned by $http like this.

In your service return the promise :

```
return  $http.get('/admin.brands/getJSONDataOfSearch').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              return data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });
```

Use `then()` on the promise in your controller :

```
  BrandService.reloadlist()
     .then(function (data){
       $scope.brands = data;      
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not angular, it's the Javascript. The function you put in `this.reloadlist` does not return any value. It has no return at all, so the value returned will be `undefined`. The success handler does return something, but it will be run long after `reloadlist` finished working.

Comment: your update is completely wrong (did you try to understand the advice?...). You still returned list before the data was read. (quote: "it will be run long after reloadList finished working").

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @fdreger already pointed out (missing return value), `$http.get(...)` is an async method. The return value is a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) not the actual value.
In order to access the value you need to return it from `reloadlist` like this:

```
this.reloadList = function() {
  return $http.get('/admin.brands/getJSONDataOfSearch');
  // you need to handle the promise in here. You could add a error handling here later by catching stuff...
}
```

and in the controller you can add it to the `$scope` like this:

```
BrandService
  .reloadlist()
  .then(function(res) {
    $scope.brands = res.data;
  });
```

The callback passed to `then()` is called as soon as the HTTP request has successfully completed, this makes the call asynchronous.

Besides the angular documentation for promises [the article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a good read too.

Comment: What is promise ? Why do I need to use it ?

Comment: @GaripTipici: this qualifies as another question . Starting angularjs without knowing JavaScript and at least trying to read up on promises is probably too many things at once.